# can we manipulate the area covered in MouseOver/Out event in areas chart: Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am developing an area chart and tracking its mouseOver event in Highcharts.

In the current behaviour the mouseover event is fired from -0.5 to point to + 0.5 .ie; ex for point one the mouse event is fired from midway between point 0 and 1 till midway of point 1 and 2.

Is it possible for me to change this from -1 till the point. ie; mouseover of point 1 is tracked from point 0 till point 1.

Comment: reproduce your example on the jsfiddle, please.

Comment: Consider the demo http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-negative  Here is it possible that the area from the marker of Oranges till the marker of Pears will come under the mouseEvent of Pears. I am not particular about the tick mark placement and labeling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not - in this particural case you are using categories, each category starts from `x - 0.5` and goes to `x + 0.5` (where x is category index). So for example Pears starts from 1.5 and ends on 2.5.

However still I'm not sure where is the problem - can't you just add 0.5 to get value you need?

Comment: I have disabled the highchart tooltip and I need to write a custom mouseOver and show a custom tooltip for the point. My requirement is to show it from x-1 to x.

Comment: Can't you use formatter for Highchahrts built-in tooltip? Another solution is to use positioner function, where you can display some other elements if you want to.

Comment: Unfortunately no. We need to show the tooltip outside the plotArea. infact outside the container Div.

Comment: Still you can return if formatter `false`, and use another div to render something, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/3TRL6/17/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! but how will this solve my problem? the tooltip will fire the same way the mouseOver is fired. correct? I show the tooltip based on the point for which the event is fired.

Comment: Okay, maybe could describe why do you need range x-1 to x, and can't subtract 0.5?

Comment: I can do that. I guess I did not get this correct. Can you please guide on which variable will show me if the event has been fired from (x-0.5) to x and which has been fired from x to x+0.5?If I can capture that info then I will be able to handle the situation.

Comment: Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/3TRL6/19/ I'm not sure if this is the way you are using mouseOver, but I hope it will answer your question. Also notice how to get value in formatter (strict category index).

Comment: Thanks. This helps. Marking your answer as correct because what I actually had in mind cannot be achieved. Will try this hack way.